# Converting OBJ data to CSS3D

Tags: html, css, 3d

I found a ton of formulae and what not, but 3D isn't my forte so I'm at a loss of what specifically to use. My goal is to convert the data in an 3D .obj file (vertices, normals, faces) to CSS3D (width, height, rotateX,Y,Z and/or similar transforms).

For example 2 simple planes

```
g plane1
# simple along along Z axis
v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  0.0  1.0
v  0.0  1.0  1.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0

g plane2
# plane rotated 90 degrees along Y-axis
v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  0.0  0.0

f  1 2 3 4
f  5 6 7 8
```

Could this data be converted to:

```
#plane1 {
    width: X;
    height: Y;
    transform: rotateX(Xdeg) rotateY(Ydeg) rotateZ(Zdeg) translateZ(Zpx)
}

#plane2 {
    width: X;
    height: Y;
    transform: rotateX(Xdeg) rotateY(Ydeg) rotateZ(Zdeg) translateZ(Zpx)
}

/* Or something equivalent such as transform: matrix3d() */
```

The core question is how to get the X/Y/Z-rotation of a 4 point plane from it's matrix of x,y,z coordinates?

**UPDATE #1 - 11/12/12**
So based on the answers provided, I've come across the unoptimized function from http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToEuler/index.htm below:

```
/*
    -v 0.940148 -0.847439 -1.052535
    -v 0.940148 -0.847439 0.947465
    -v -1.059852 -0.847439 0.947465
    -v -1.059852 -0.847439 -1.052535
    -v 0.940148 1.152561 -1.052534
    -v 0.940147 1.152561 0.947466
    -v -1.059852 1.152561 0.947465
    v -1.059852 1.152561 -1.052535

    f 1 2 3 4
    f 5 8 7 6
    f 1 5 6 2
    f 2 6 7 3
    f 3 7 8 4
    f 5 1 4 8
*/

var f = {
    'm00' : 0.940148,
    'm01' : -0.847439,
    'm02' : -1.052535,
    'm10' : 0.940148,
    'm11' : -0.847439,
    'm12' : 0.947465,
    'm20' : -1.059852,
    'm21' : -0.847439,
    'm22' : 0.947465
}

// Assuming the angles are in radians.
if (f.m10 > 0.998) { // singularity at north pole
    heading = Math.atan2(f.m02, f.m22);
    attitude = Math.PI/2;
    bank = 0;
} else if (f.m10 < -0.998) { // singularity at south pole
    heading = Math.atan2(f.m02,f.m22);
    attitude = -Math.PI/2;
    bank = 0;
} else {
    heading = Math.atan2(-f.m20, f.m00);
    bank = Math.atan2(-f.m12, f.m11);
    attitude = Math.asin(f.m10);
}
```

I'm getting results, but I'm not sure if my calculations are correct and I'm also getting mixed responses on what corresponds to which axis. Is it heading = y, bank = x, and attitude = z? I'm also converting each to degrees if that matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of Matrix to Euler angles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137591/matrix-to-eulerangles

Comment: Did You measure performance? Make benchmark with desired amount of css3d transformations based on random input values. If it will lag on target machine then your work will be waste of time. Average obj file contains huge amount of faces.

Comment: It wasn't an issue of performance. It came down to blatant incorrect math on my part. The OBJ files being used are being created specifically with CSS3D in mind so they will have a minimal amount of polygons.

Comment: And it will be really hard(or impossible) to implement, bended quads,  triangles, normals, texture coordinates. CSS3D implementation will be strongly limited.

Comment: I was going to have the person modeling only use four sided polys. In theory, I was hoping to place a bunch of four sided polys and have their x,y,z position determine angle and everything form an object.

Comment: Did you get it to work? Sounds very interesting! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Read this http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_matrix.html  It explains pretty much everything and there is implementation.

Beside that the CSS 3D solution will have lower performance(order of magnitude) mainly because each pice of represented surface is DOM element, it's also highly limited - you can find numerous materials about this issue(Google IO records for example)

If you need declarative 3D framework you might want to look at [x3dom](http://www.x3dom.org/)

To draw a 3D box you just need to include x3dom js script and embed this declaration in your page:

```
 <body> 
   <h1>Hello X3DOM World</h1> 
   <x3d width="400" height="300"> 
     <scene> 
       <shape> 
         <box></box> 
      </shape> 
     </scene> 
   </x3d> 
 </body>
```

It will parse <x3d> tags on your page and generate proper WebGL or Flash implementation with the good performance.

x3d has way to import assets from Blender, Maya and 3ds Max. 
Here is some good reading: [x3domIntroTutorial.pdf](http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/doc/slides/x3domIntroTutorial.pdf)

*IE 11 will support [WebGL](http://caniuse.com/webgl) and IE10 will autoupdate to IE 11 so only non-supporting desktop browser(disabled by default) will be Safari. Apple will be forced to enable it by default. With full desktop support it won't take too long to get full mobile because it's highly competitive market. And we have highly accessible WebGL framework like three.js. So there is no sense in doing it with CSS 3D*

**UPDATE: iOS 8 Safari will enable WebGL support by default: http://caniuse.com/webgl**

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm typically a late adopter to these kind of technologies, but the information above is more than enough to get me started on a more proper path.

Comment: @DonBoots 3D frameworks allows you to make this transition as smooth as possible. At this point no one on this planet can know everything about 3d graphic it's just too large and too deep. But with good tool set you can learn new things gradually and rely on the frameworks default behaviors in some complex cases.